# How to to grouping and ordering on an object of two different types of list?

Tags: c#, list, linq, sql-order-by, grouping

I have an object of two different types of list and i want to do `OrderBy` and `GroupBy` on that particular object only.

I don't want to do it separately for both the list.

Right now i am doing this:

```
List<object> combinePlacePerson = (from x in recipientFilteredDataByPersons.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).GroupBy(x => x.FirstName[0]) select (object)x).ToList();
combinePlacePerson.AddRange((from x in recipientFilteredDataByPlaces.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).GroupBy(x => x.FirstName[0]) select (object)x).ToList());
cvrbyperson.Source = combinePlacePerson;
```

`cvrbyperson` is a `CollectionViewSource` object.

But i want to do it on combined object.

Comment: How are creating recipientFilteredDataByPersons and recipientFilteredDataByPlaces? What type of list they are? Objects of them have some properties in common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface like this:

```
public interface IHaveFirstName
{
   string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Inherit your classes that inside properties `recipientFilteredDataByPersons` `recipientFilteredDataByPlaces` from this interface

Now you're able to do this:

```
List<IHaveFirstName> combinePlacePerson = (from x in recipientFilteredDataByPersons 
                        select (IHaveFirstName)x).ToList(); //you need inheritance here
combinePlacePerson.AddRange((from x in recipientFilteredDataByPlaces 
                        select (IHaveFirstName)x).ToList()); //and here
//here you order full collection
combinePlacePerson = combinePlacePerson.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName)
                                       .GroupBy(x => x.FirstName[0]);
```